# Microsoft Graph API Scripted Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

How does one authenticate as a user without any direct user interaction?

---

Otherwise i found a workaround with client credential flow in this example : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-snippets-sample
but if i try to implement this code in an c# Asp.net mav applcition or a windows forms application i cant get an application token. If i debug the app it stuck at waiting for token but it doesn't throw an error (virus protection already deactivated). Does anyone have a idea for the main problem or my workaround?

This is the Code for my workaround trying to get a token, but stuck on daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync.

```
   public async Task<Users> GetUser(string Username)
    {
        MSALCache appTokenCache = new MSALCache(clientId);

        ClientCredential clientdummy = new ClientCredential(clientSecret);
        
        ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId), redirectUri,
                                                            clientdummy, null, null);

        authenticate(daemonClient).Wait();

        string token = authResult.AccessToken;

        client = GetAuthenticatedClientForApp(token);

        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = client.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result;
    }

    private async Task<AuthenticationResult> authenticate(ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient)
    {
        authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { MSGraphScope });
        return authResult;
    }
```

Comment: Not knowing about the Graph API, but it might be better if you would show your code. "... try to implement this code in a c# Asp.net ..." probably is far too unclear.

Comment: @Binarus i insert the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

Found Workaround Solution: getting a Token via REST API. Here I can get an User token or an Client token to access to graph api:

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + domainname);
 var request = new RestRequest("/oauth2/token", Method.POST);   request.AddBody("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
        request.AddParameter("Resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
        request.AddParameter("scope", "[scopes]"); 
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        //contains the token 
        var content = response.Content;
```

Comment: I'm doing nearly the same. But my `grant_type` is `password` and my `scope` is `openid` to get a user token from username and password.

Comment: I had to use request.AddParameter instead of request.AddBody for the grant_type parameter.  Also for the Graph API endpoint I'm using I left out the Resource parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you need a solution to authenticate a user without any interaction.

We can get an Access Token by some background services or daemons.

For more details, we can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

Base on my test, we can try the following steps:

First, we should get administrator consent:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                                           {
                                               ClientId = clientId,
                                               Authority = authority,
                                               RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                                               PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                                               Scope = "openid profile",
                                               ResponseType = "id_token",
                                               TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false, NameClaimType = "name" },
                                               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                                                               {
                                                                   AuthenticationFailed = this.OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                                                                   SecurityTokenValidated = this.OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync
                                                               }
                                           });



ConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.clientId, string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId), Startup.redirectUri,
                                                                                       new ClientCredential(Startup.clientSecret), null, appTokenCache.GetMsalCacheInstance());
AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { MSGraphScope });
```

Then, we can use this access token to using the Graph APIs.

For more details, we can review to [v2.0 daemon sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks i implemented this in my code. In the Code example i get a authresult. But if i use my code it waiting for daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync but never get a token

Comment: Yes, you can get the access token at the authorize API controller.Did you use the simple code on Github?

Comment: yes i get a access token with the code on github. But when i implement it in my project and debug it waits for a token but never receive one

Comment: If you use the simple code, you can get the access token by using this code ` authProvider.GetUserAccesstokenAsync();` at the position where you want to use the accesstoken